# Регулярное выражение поиска HTML тега по id

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения

Нужно найти тег с уникальным id, я использую [такое регулярное выражение](https://regex101.com/r/H2yGq8/1/), ожидаю результат

```
   <p id="editable4" class="editable">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
             adipisicing elit. Ad, veniam in tempora voluptatum vel
             sequi, nulla, corporis nobis eum aliquid molestiae porro
             culpa doloribus. At eveniet quaerat possimus tempora nulla.
     </p>
```

но получается регулярное выражение ищет последний закраивающий тег всех параграфов.

```
<p id="editable4" class="editable">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
        adipisicing elit. Ad, veniam in tempora voluptatum vel
        sequi, nulla, corporis nobis eum aliquid molestiae porro
        culpa doloribus. At eveniet quaerat possimus tempora nulla.
</p>
<br>
<div  id="editable_div" class="editable">
 DIV sequi, nulla, corporis nobis eum aliquid molestiae porro
        culpa doloribus. At eveni
</div>
<br>
<h3 id="editable5" class="editable">
    h3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur 
</h3>
<p id="editable6"  class="editable">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
        adipisicing elit. Ad, veniam in tempora voluptatum vel
        sequi, nulla, corporis nobis eum aliquid molestiae porro
        culpa doloribus. At eveniet quaerat possimus tempora nulla.
</p>
```

Как найти только тег с уникальным id?

Comment: Квантификаторы по умолчанию - жадные, и ваш `[\s\S]*` съедает всё. Добавьте после звёздочки вопросительный знак: `[\s\S]*?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уменьшите "жадность", заменив:

```
<(\w+)\s[^>]*id=\"editable4\"[^>]*>[\s\S]*\1>
```

на

```
<(\w+)\s[^>]*id=\"editable4\"[^>]*>[\s\S]*?\1>
```

Но на мой взгляд использовать регулярные выражения для извлечения тегов не совсем оптимальный подход. Если есть возможность, то лучше использовать DOM.

Помимо этого часть регулярного выражения `[^>]*`, которая "говорит" любой символ кроме `>` 0 и более раз, не будет корректно работать во всех случаях, так как символ `>` может встречаться в содержимом атрибутов, например в `title="One is > as zero"`. В любом случае Вам придётся учитывать все возможные варианты и со временем регулярное выражение превратится в неуклюжего и непонятного монстра.

Если Вы используете JavaScript, то можно использовать [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
var xmlString = "<p>...</p><p id="editable4" class="editable">...</p>";
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
```

Для других языков программирования также, как правило, существуют библиотеки для парсинга XML.